# Setting a variable within a link_to, in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to

I am trying to set variables in a series of link_to links, so that each link is associated with a value.

---

On one page I have a loop which creates a list of links from values in my database:

```
<ul>
  <% @alldata.each do |x| %>
    <li><%= link_to "#{x.name}", charts_path %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

The charts_path links to a view which displays a chartkick graph:

```
<%= line_chart @data.group("year").sum("magnitude") %>
```

which gets its data from a controller saying:

```
def graphdata(x)
  @data = Model.all.where(name: x).select("magnitude, year")
end

def charts(?variable)
  @data = graphdata(?variable)
end
```

I would like to alter my list loop to set ?variable to x.name. For example something like:

```
<li><%= link_to "#{x.name}", charts_path, ?variable = "#{x.name}" %></li>
```

So that I have a list of links, that route to different charts with data specific to that link.

---

I could define a specific view for every single name:

```
def chart1
  @data = graphdata("name1")
end

def chart2
  @data = graphdata("name2")
end
```

But that seems like very bad programming...

---

I'm sorry if this question is poor, I'm extremely new to programming.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Try Using this Code.

```
<%= link_to "#{x.name}", charts_path(x.name) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to pass the name of `x` as a querystring variable. You can easily do this with the `charts_path` helper:

```
<%= link_to "#{x.name}", charts_path(variable: x.name) %>
```

charts_path accepts a hash that will be passed with the request

Comment: thank you for your help, I had to pick up the variable using params[:variable], in the controller for my charts, then it worked a treat

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the similar state where I got my module worked with the following method

```
`<%= link_to n.subject, notifications_message_path(notification_id: n.id)%>`
```